# iPhone UITableViewController and Labels related

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController List showing text containing hyperlinks and I have a label which displays hyperlinks in a special manner so that they are clickable.

I want that, when a user clicks on any UITableViewCell then the label would turn on the links in clickable form and when the user scrolls the UITableViewController List the Label should turn back to normal form.

Where from I would get the user has scrolled the list or not.

And whats the correct location and correct way to customize UITableViewCell.

Please any light in this way would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Listen for [UITableViewDelegate tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW13) and [UIScrollViewDelegate scrollViewWillBeginDragging:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006923-CH3-SW1)

Comment: Okay I got the scrolling working now but I had another issue, I want to change some contents of the cell when the user selects the cell how i'm supposed to do this can you give me some light on this.

Comment: that all depends on what is inside your cell, and what type of cell it is

Comment: Its a simple UITableViewCell with some labels and UIImageView similar to the ones we can see in some live iPhone apps like tvider

Comment: in that case, change the properties using the setter methods